# SQL Code in home rolled gridview search results not displaying correct results

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-server-2012

I'm in the process of trying to troubleshoot some SQL code in an ASP/C# gridview search that I rolled myself.  I have a search box that searches on specific fields but the twist here is that I only want results after a certain row.

In this database I have a sequence command that autogenerates a number in a column called 'record_number' for every entry in this table and only want results after record #500.  The entries are created manually via a different page.

Right now my search code is as follows:

```
"SelectCommand="SELECT [record_number], [column_a], [column_b], [column_c], [column_d], [column_e], [column_f], [column_g], [column_h], [column_i], [column_j] FROM [schema].[table_name] WHERE record_number >= 500 AND ([column_a] LIKE '%' + @column_a + '%') OR ([column_c] LIKE '%' + @column_c + '%') OR ([column_e] LIKE '%' + @column_e + '%') OR ([column_g] LIKE '%' + @column_g + '%') OR ([column_h] LIKE '%' + @column_h + '%') OR ([column_j] LIKE '%' + @column_j + '%')"
```

I can post my SelectParameters if needed or anything else.  The challenge I'm facing is when I run a search for just the letter 'c' leveraging this code, the results that post have a record_number less AND greater than than 500. At this point I'm spinning my wheels as I'm not seeing where the problem lies.

If more information is needed by the masses, please let me know.

EDIT

Forgot this part - I've tried moving around the commands and consolidating the commands but no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my question answered on the [Database Administrators board](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44410/home-rolled-gridview-search-results-shows-rows-that-are-supposed-to-be-ignored).  My OR clause was breaking the query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping all the OR statements in your query in () It almost looks as if it's reading it as:

```
(record_number >= 500 AND ([column_a] LIKE '%' + @column_a + '%')) OR ([column_e] LIKE '%' + @column_e + '%') OR ([column_g] LIKE '%' + @column_g + '%') OR ([column_h] LIKE '%' + @column_h + '%') OR ([column_j] LIKE '%' + @column_j + '%')
```

rather than:

```
record_number >= 500 AND (([column_a] LIKE '%' + @column_a + '%') OR ([column_e] LIKE '%' + @column_e + '%') OR ([column_g] LIKE '%' + @column_g + '%') OR ([column_h] LIKE '%' + @column_h + '%') OR ([column_j] LIKE '%' + @column_j + '%'))
```

the difference being that it sees the >= 500 plus the first statement for column_a as one condition in which case the other conditions can be true as well resulting in results that are record_number < 500.

not sure if that's your problem, but I would give that a go.